# asignar atributo un elemento de un Array

Tags: javascript

Tras unas dudas ya resueltas por aqui en Stackoverflow, me llega el siguiente problema.

Tengo una tabla dinámica, en una de las páginas el contenido es el siguiente:

```js
var fechaActual = new Date();
    var divTrabajo = $('.work-class');
    var ultimaModificacionTrabajo = $('.date-work-edited').data('act').split('/');
    var fechaModificado = new Date(ultimaModificacionTrabajo[2],ultimaModificacionTrabajo[1] - 1, ultimaModificacionTrabajo[0] );
    fechaModificado.setDate(fechaModificado.getDate() + 2);

    if (fechaModificado < fechaActual){
        divTrabajo.css('color','red');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sortable" class="table mt-4 no-arrow">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>O.I.</a></th>
        <th>REF. TRABAJO</a></th>
        <th>CLIENTE</a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="17/03/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

El objetivo del script es resaltar poniendo en rojo las columnas que estén con la fecha "expirada".

Según el funcionamiento que deseo, la última columna no debe de tener el color rojo, ya que no cumple la condición que le he puesto. Pero claro, la condición la he realizado sin nombrar a que posición del array se le hace dicha condición.

No sé como proceder para asignar la condición a cada item del array, y así marcar solo y exclusivamente las columnas que no cumplan la condición.

Lo que genera la tabla, es un `foreach` en Laravel:

```
@foreach($worksInFase->items() as $work)
                <tr class="work-class">
                    <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="{{$work->latestActivity->momento}}">
                        <input value="{{ $work->id }}" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route("oi.edit", $work->oi["id"]) }}">{{ $work->oi["id"] }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route("work.edit", $work->id) }}">{{ $work->id }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route("client.edit", $work->id_cliente) }}">{{ $work->client->nombre }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $work->npedido  }}

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $work->nombre }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $work->workType->nombre }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $work->cantidad }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $work->store->nombre }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route("fase",$work->fase->id) }}">{{ $work->fase->nombre }}</a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a data-val="{{ $work->id }}" class="pdf_trigger" title="generate a pdf" href="#"><i style="font-size: 26px;" class="far fa-file-pdf float-left"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Dices que la tabla se genera dinamicamente pero en el código que has subido no muestras en ningún lado la función que la genera. Sería útil que mostrases esa parte del código puesto que es seguramente en la que haya que intervenir para conseguir lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola Myguel, es un foreach de Laravel, te lo dejo mostrado..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//Se capturan todos los elementos de la clase work-class 
//para almacenarlos en una variable
var divTrabajo = $('.work-class');

//Se recorre cada uno de los elementos para poder hacer las comprobaciones
//pertinentes por cada uno de ellos
divTrabajo.each(function() {
    var fechaActual = new Date();
    //Se recoge la fecha que tenga el atributo data-act, solamente del item
    //en el que estamos iterando.
    var ultimaModificacionTrabajo = $(this).find('.date-work-edited').data('act').split('/');
     var fechaModificado = new Date(ultimaModificacionTrabajo[2],ultimaModificacionTrabajo[1] - 1, ultimaModificacionTrabajo[0] );
    fechaModificado.setDate(fechaModificado.getDate() + 2);
    
    //Se le cambia el color solamente al item que estamos iterando
    if (fechaModificado < fechaActual){
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sortable" class="table mt-4 no-arrow">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>O.I.</a></th>
        <th>REF. TRABAJO</a></th>
        <th>CLIENTE</a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="30/01/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="work-class">
        <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="17/03/2019">
            <input value="346" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="trabajos_change[]">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
           #
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Creo que se podría solucionar tocando solamente el **frontend**. La lógica de comparación de fechas que tienes montada es buena, pero el problema es que con `var divTrabajo = $('.work-class')` estás seleccionando todos los items del **DOM** que posean esa clase, por lo que al hacer la comprobación lo estás haciendo con todos a la vez. Esto ocasiona que en el momento en que alguno de los items cumpla la condición siempre se va a meter por el `if`. Además de que lo que tú quieres es que se pinten de rojo solamente los que no la cumplan, tal y como lo tienes hecho se colorearían todos de rojo.

La solución que te propongo parte de la función `each()` de Jquery y del uso del `this` para poder referenciar al item que toque en cada iteración del bucle. De esta manera, podemos hacer referencia a cada uno de los item con la clase `.work-class` y hacer la comprobación entre fechas de manera individual.

Comment: Estupendo!!! muchisimas gracias!